# In app purchasing, automatic cancellation of lower tier when purchasing higher tier subscriptions

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

In my application i plan to have different subscription-IAP:s.

**1. basic** - tier 1

**2. premium** - tier 2

**3. pro** - tier 3

I am under the assumption that every user will start off with the **basic** subscription. Should they enjoy the application, they can buy **additional subscriptions** later on.

**To my question:**

If I have purchased basic subscription, and now would like premium features. How can I automatically cancel my basic subscription upon a premium purchase? I would not want my users to end up with double fees every month.

**For me**, this question targets both Google and Apple stores and in-app management.

Comment: just add condition, like if(tier1_purchase===true){ enable a boolean value to yes} then for tier 2 and tier 3 first check for the bool value if its true then set the tier value lower then the original value ...something like that work for you

Comment: You mean actual repeating subscriptions, not just changing the UI, yes?

Comment: Yes, i mean repeating subscriptions. Imagine you have a gym-card for 20$/month. Suddenly you would like to also get access to the pool at the gym, so you extend your subscriptions. now 30$/month. I wan't to avoid my users paying 50$/month i.e. ending up with double subscriptions.